# Jira & Greenhopper - How to show total of Story Points per column on Task Board instead of total in hours

Tags: jira, jira-agile

Using Jira 4.4 and Greenhopper 5.8.4

On the TaskBoard I'd like to show the total of story points for the column (state) rather than the total hours.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question and obvious feature request indeed -  I don't think that is currently possible and there is a related (though not identical) user story filed already:

- [As project manager, I'd like to customize the progress bar to show the progress in term of story points not cards count (GHS-2990)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-2990)

It doesn't seem to have much attention yet, so to increase the chance of this being available you might add your vote/comment there to generalize this requirement and/or file a dedicated story addressing your use case specifically.

Please be aware though, that the [Task Board](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Task+Board) has been scheduled to be superseded by the new and much more flexible [Rapid Board](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Rapid+Board), once the latter encompasses all features (well, guess most at least) currently available within the Task Board - see [The Future of GreenHopper](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/The+Future+of+GreenHopper) for details, it boils down to:

> The Rapid Board removes the complexity of the existing user interface
>   (projects, contexts, boards, filters, versions, etc) while retaining
>   the flexibility of GreenHopper. In fact, with the Rapid Board,
>   GreenHopper is now a whole lot more flexible due to our use of the
>   JIRA Query Language.

Fortunately the GreenHopper team is approaching this transition in a defensive and compatible manner, but obviously I wouldn't expect any new features to be added to the now considered 'Classic Mode' either:

> In GreenHopper 6.0 we plan to push the existing boards (Planning,
>   Task, Chart and Released Boards) to a Classic Mode and drop the
>   "Rapid" title. The existing functionality on the Planning, Task, Chart
>   and Released Boards will continue to be available for a number of
>   releases until it becomes clear that the majority of customers have
>   switched over.

Comment: Classic boards no longer worked on, only Rapid Boards will receive continued development. The linked user story is resolved as "do not fix".

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Javascript solution to display storypoints on the Scrum/Kanban boards.

The script is attached to [this](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-6755) jira issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary measure, I've written a SQL query to get this data:

```
select v.vname as theVersion, s.pname as statusName, sum(cfv.numbervalue) as totalStoryPoints
from jiraissue i
join issuestatus s
  on i.issuestatus = s.ID
join nodeassociation a
  on a.source_node_id = i.id
join projectversion v
  on a.sink_node_id = v.ID
join customfield cf
  on cf.cfname = 'Story Points'
join customfieldvalue cfv
  on cf.ID = cfv.customfield
  and cfv.ISSUE = i.ID
group by v.vname, s.pname
```